# Two random variables $U$, $V$ such that the conditional distribution of $U$ given $V = v$ is $ve^{-u}$ for $u > ln(v)$. Prove the following:

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given two random variables $U$ and $V$ such that the conditional PDF of $U$ given $V = v$ is $ve^{-u}$ for $u > ln(v)$, prove $U - V$ conditional on $V = v$ follows $Exp(1)$.

Intuitively, why is this true? My attempt:

Let $Z = U - V$.

$P(Z <= z | V = v) = P(U - v <= z | V = v) = P(U <= z + v | V = v)$

Differentiating with respect to $z$, we see that the desired PDF is $ve^{-(z+v)}$. But this is not an exponential distribution with parameter $1$.. what have I done wrong?

Comment: I guess you should be more careful about the condition $u > \log v$ in the original conditional distribution definition.

Comment: As for the intuitive approach. How about you plot the PDF for some (positive!) values of $v$? You'll notice that, after shifting the origin to the point $(v,0)$, the function looks always the same... Why is that? And what function is that?

Comment: $U-V$ conditional on $V$ is not Exp(1) as you have found. This is also clear from the fact that $E(U-V\mid V=v)=E(U\mid V=v)-v=\ln v-v+1\ne 1$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom ops, you're right, of course. My comments above would be valid if the random variable $Z$ were defined as $U-\log V$, correct?

Comment: @dfnu My comment was directed to OP.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, I know! :)